# How to set value of select box into database of a specific user

Tags: php

I have a dashboard where I can access all users data. In dashboard area I have select box option where I can change users roles (select box values are dynamic) the only thing I want to do is to update roles from select box option of a specific user.

Here is my code

```
 <tbody>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user");
$i = 1;
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $i++?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $fetch['Name']?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $fetch['Email']?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $fetch['Role']?> </td>
<td class="user-priority-5"><div id="mainselection">
<select name="change_role">
<option>Select Role</option>
<?php 
$roles_query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user_roles");
while ($roles = mysqli_fetch_array($roles_query))
{echo "<option value='".$roles['role_id']."'>".$roles['roles']."</option>";}?>
</select>
</div></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What you have shown here might well happily display the users and their associated "role" but there is nothing that approaches the topic of updating their roles so it is unclear what the issue is. You can use an AJAX function bound to an `onchange` event  - the ajax function sends a request to a backend script that updates that user role based upon the new selected value.

Comment: will you please show me an example how to do that?

Comment: I also have a button on that page I want to change role of a specific user when I click on that button

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how you MIGHT do the updating of the user record as per the comment I made ~ I should stress that this is wholly untested!
The general idea is that you obtain a reference to all the `select` menus and assign an event listener to each. The event listener sends an ajax request ( here using `fetch` for brevity ) which sends the ID and the newly selected ROLE to a backend script.
The backend script uses the POSTed values to update the record ( using a prepared statement ).... semi-pseudo code...

Update

There was a small error/omission in the javascript posted initially. Rather than `let parent=e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;` it should, of course, have been `let parent=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;`

An 'end-to-end' example ~ it just so happens that one particular db has an identical structure so it was easy to generate the example and test it.

```
<?php
    require 'dbconn.php'; #whatever...

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) && !empty( $_POST['role'] ) ){
        /*
            To emulate remote script that is targeted by the ajax request.
        */
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $role=$_POST['role'];
        
        $sql='update `users` set `role`=? where `id`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('si',$role,$id);
        $res=$stmt->execute();
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        
        http_response_code(200);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json=json_encode(array(
            'status'    =>  $res,
            'updated'   =>  $rows,
            'id'        =>  $id,
            'role'      =>  $role
        ));
        exit($json);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
        
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                
                const message=function(n,m){
                    n.textContent=m;
                    setTimeout(()=>{n.textContent=''},2500);
                };
                
                document.querySelectorAll('select[name="change_role"]').forEach( sel=>{
                    sel.addEventListener('change',function(e){
                        let span=e.target.nextElementSibling;
                        let parent=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;   //  this should be the TR
                        let id=parent.firstElementChild.textContent;            //  this *SHOULD* get the ID from the first table cell in the current row. There are better ways - hidden fields, dataset attributes etc
                        
                        let fd=new FormData();
                            fd.append('id',id);
                            fd.append('role',e.target.value);
                            
                        let url=location.href;  //path/to/backend/script.php
                        
                        fetch( location.href, { method:'post',body:fd } )
                            .then( r=>{ return r.json() } )
                            .then( json=>{
                                /* 
                                    Use this callback function to do whatever you need to indicate to the user
                                    that the record has been updated. Here a simple message is displayed in a
                                    SPAN element 
                                */
                                console.info( json );
                                message( span, 'OK' )
                                
                            })
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                /*
                    We only need to query the db once for the list of roles
                    so do not execute the same query in a loop as originally.
                */
                $sql='select * from user_roles;';
                $res=$db->query( $sql );
                $arr=$res->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
                
                
                
                
                #fetch user details
                $sql='select 
                        u.id,
                        u.name,
                        u.email,
                        r.roles as `role`,
                        u.role as `rid` 
                    from users u 
                        join user_roles r on r.id=u.role';
                        
                $res = $db->query( $sql );
                
                #iterate over all rows
                while( $rs = $res->fetch_object() ) {
                    printf(
                        '
                        <tr>
                            <td>%d</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td class="user-priority-5">
                                <div class="mainselection">
                                    <select name="change_role">
                                        <option selected hidden disabled>Select Role', 
                        $rs->id,
                        $rs->name,
                        $rs->email,
                        $rs->role
                    );
                    
                    
                    #generate dropdown menu from array
                    foreach( $arr as $row ){
                        $selected=$row['id']==$rs->rid ? 'selected' : '';
                        
                        printf(
                            '<option value="%d"%s>%s',
                            $row['id'],
                            $selected,
                            $row['roles']
                        );
                    }
                    
                    
                    echo '              
                                </select>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                
                
                
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help i tried this but my page got blanked it displays nothing

Comment: will you please explain me where to put database column names in this code like user id etc i am little bit confused